# How can I use TarteAuCitron (RGPD / ePR) with ContactForm7 integrated reCAPTCHA?

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

I’m using the script [tarteaucitron.js](https://github.com/AmauriC/tarteaucitron.js) on a client’s website to manage third party cookies and scripts. The website is WordPress powered.

We have a contact form created with the [ContactForm7](http://contactform7.com/) extension with the integrated reCAPTCHA.

I’d like to have TarteAuCitron handle the reCAPTCHA script instead of ContactForm7 loading it. I know that TarteAuCitron is able to load reCAPTCHA but I don’t know how to use it in combination with ContactForm7 settings and WordPress scripts system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. In a WordPress action hook (`wp_footer`), I dequeue the reCAPTCHA script which is enqueued by Contact Form 7. I then insert a custom TarteAuCitron service and service call (different for reCAPTCHA v2 and v3), then the Contact Form 7 bootstrap script:

```
// remove recaptcha script
wp_dequeue_script('google-recaptcha');

// enqueue recaptcha service
// $service contains the definition script of the TarteAuCitron service named 'recaptchacf7'
wp_add_inline_script('tarteaucitron', $service, 'after');

// enqueue service call
wp_add_inline_script('tarteaucitron', '(tarteaucitron.job = tarteaucitron.job || []).push("recaptchacf7");', 'after');
```

With reCAPCHA v3, the tricky part is to retreive the Contact Form 7 bootstrap script which is not enqueued in a standard way but simply written during the `wp_footer` action. We need to prevent its immediate insertion, and insert it in the service definition script for later activation if website user choses to enable it. I did this with the help of the `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` PHP functions:

```
if (function_exists('wpcf7_recaptcha_onload_script')) {
    array_push(wp_scripts()->done, 'google-recaptcha');
    ob_start();
    wpcf7_recaptcha_onload_script();
    $bootstrap = preg_replace('/<\/?script[^>]*>/', '', ob_get_clean());
    array_pop(wp_scripts()->done);
}
```

I wrapped the code in a WordPress plugin which can be found here : [cf7-tac-recaptcha](https://github.com/jerome-rdlv/cf7-tac-recpatcha). It includes services definition scripts for reCAPTCHA v2 and v3. There’s nothing more to configure.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)